# Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension and Invalid Configuration - CommandToExecute is present in both protected and public configuration sections

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I m trying to customize a vm with Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension and I ve got this error all the time :
Invalid Configuration - CommandToExecute is present in both protected and public configuration sections

the command is as follow

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName XXX -Location XXXX -VMName XXXXX -Name post_config -FileName create_databases_mssql2.ps1 -ContainerName XXXX -StorageAccountName XXXX -Run create_databases_mssql2.ps1 -Argument "-u $username -p $password -db_user $loginName -dbpwd $password_db"

the script is very simple
create_databases_mssql2.ps1:

New-Item -path "F:\Datas2\Prod" -type directory
New-Item -path "G:\Logs2\Prod" -type directory
```

Comment: remove the extension completely and retry?

Answer (score 0):

> Only one version of an extension can be installed on a VM at a point in time, specifying custom script twice in the same Resource Manager template for the same VM will fail.

When you both install [Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-2.3.2) and [Set-AzVMExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-2.3.2), the error will happen. So, [remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/remove-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-2.3.2) the extension completely and try again, it will work.

Here is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) about Custom Script Extension for Windows you could follow.